# PHP Get images from sub directories

Tags: php, scandir

I was having below code before for getting images from a perticular folder.
now i want to get images on a single page from multiple folders
i have folder name name as "images" than inside "images" folder i have folderOne, folderTwo, folderThree.. .jpg files are only in these sub folders

Below code i had before >>>

```
<?php

    function scd($dir)  
    {$files = scandir($dir);

    asort($files);
    return $files;
    }   

    $output = '<div> ';
    $dir = "images";
    $files = scd($dir);
    foreach($files as $file){
    shuffle($files);
    if($file==='.' || $file==='...'){continue;}

    $output.='<img src="'.$dir.'/'.$file.' " />';
        }
        echo $output. "</div>";

?>
```

with this code its only shows files which are in "images folder and it does not get files from sub directories.

Please Help.. Thanks advance..!

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Answer (score 3):

I would personally suggest [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator) instead of `scandir()`

```
<?php

function scd($path) {
    $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

    $files = [];
    foreach ($iterator as $file) {
        $files[] = $file;
    }

    asort($files);
    return $files;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that, @meda. :)